# Troubles with Haskell program to find ther median of a list

Tags: haskell

I need to write a haskell program that prompts for a sequence of integers from the user, one integer for each line, ending with a blank line to mark the end. Once the end of list is indicated, the program finds the median of the list created and prompts if the user wants to go again.

Ive spent quite a bit of time on this but am very new to haskell and can't seem to make my code compile. Here's what i have so far:

```
module Main where

import System.IO
import Data.List

-- median.hs


-- Repeatedly prompt the user for numbers to find the median of. Ends by
-- asking the user if they want to go again. User types y to go again or
-- anything else to end the program

-- User needs to enter only a single integer on each line, ending with
-- a blank line entered. If this isn't followed the program will crash.


median = do

    let list = []

    putStr "This is a basic program that finds the median of a list of numbers entered."
    putStr "To enter the list, enter each number individually followed by a blank line to end your list."
    putStr ""
    putStr "*********************************************************************************************************"
    putStr "*********************************************************************************************************"
    putStr ""
    putStr "Begin entering the list"
    putStr ""

    putStr "Type a single number: "
    hFlush stdout
    line <- getLine
    let n = read line
    if (n == Nothing)
        then
            "No values entered, restarting program"
            median

        else
            n:list

    putStr ""         --List fully entered, calculate median and print value
    putStr "The median of your number is: "

    let newList = createList list where
        createList list = do
            putStr "Type a single number or nothing to complete the list: "
            hFlush stdout
            input <- getLine
            do
                case input of
                    Nothing -> Nothing
                    x -> createList (x:list)

    let med = calcMedian newList where
        calcMedian :: [Integer] -> Integer
        calcMedian [] = 0
        calcMedian xs = result where
            result = do
                if (n `mod` 2 == 0) then getMiddle sorted else head $ drop a sorted where
                    getMiddle [] = 0
                    getMiddle xs = (a' + b') `div` 2 where
                        a' = head $ drop a xs
                        b' = head $ drop b xs
                        a = (n `div` 2)
                        b = n' - 1
                        n' = n `div` 2
                        n = length xs
            a = (n - 1) `div` 2
            n = length xs
            sorted = sort xs

    show med
    putStr "Would you like to go again? (y or n): "
    hFlush stdout
    line <- getLine

    let n = read line
        if (line == "y")
            then
                median
            else
                return ()

main = median
```

Comment: can't seem to make my code compile? Please attach any error message you are getting

Comment: Start by breaking your code into smaller, easier-to-manage pieces. `getMedian`, for example, should be defined as a separate function, not in the middle of the IO action that will use it.

Comment: Also, you misusing the `do` notation; it's for simplifying monadic operations, not just introducting a block of code.

Comment: Right now, i can't get past "parse error"  on main = median

Comment: that whole code block is riddled with bugs. it is impossible to fully address in less than 20 pages of text or so. :( and the fact that the error message wasn't included didn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit too broad: I'll focus only on the first part where you read the input.

```
putStr "Type a single number: "
    hFlush stdout
    line <- getLine
    let n = read line
    if (n == Nothing)
        then
            "No values entered, restarting program"
            median

        else
            n:list
```

Here you use strings (`"No values entered, restarting program"`) and lists (`n:list`) as if they were IO actions, but they are not. To read input, I recommend writing an auxiliary recursive helper. Here's an example:

```
getNumberList :: IO [Integer]
getNumberList = do
   putStr "Type a single number: "
   hFlush stdout
   line <- getLine
   case line of
      "" -> return []   -- no more numbers to read
      _  -> do          -- a number was entered
         let n = read line
         rest <- getNumberList  -- recursively read the others
         return (n:rest)
```

Answer (score 0):

`n:list` does not add `n` to beginning of list `list`. It creates a **new** list containing `n` at index 0 followed by list `list`.

Try that in ghci:

`let a = [] -- creates an empty list called a
0:a -- creates a new list but does nothing with the result
let b = 0:a -- creates a new list and save that value in b`

Now value of `a` is `[]` and value of `b` is `[0]`

Answer (score 0):

The parse error you're getting is the result of the last block of code:

```
let n = read line
    if (line == "y")
        then
            median
        else
            return ()
```

Because the `if` construct is indented, I believe it's being parsed as another `let` binding, like this:

```
let x = 1
    y = 1 + x
```

and the parser is very confused by the time it hits `main`.

I think perhaps you meant:

```
let n = read line
if (line == "y")
    then
        median
    else
        return ()
```